# Escaping a string with a single quote in parameterized query with node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

**The issue**

I'm currently facing an issue using node-postgres parameterized queries:

```js
const pg = require('pg'); // Latest package version yet, 8.8.0
// ...Skipping connecting stuff...
const searchString = "%let's do it%";
const res = pg.query('SELECT name FROM folders WHERE name ILIKE $1', [searchString]);
```

I originally thought that the parameterized query was supposed to handle the escaping mechanism on its own, but in fact it doesn't appear to be the case, this query causing the following error to be thrown on the postgres server:
`42601: syntax error at or near "let"`

**First try**

When I try to manually escape the string with a double quote:

```js
const searchString = "%let's do it%";
const res = pg.query('SELECT name FROM folders WHERE name ILIKE $1', [searchString.replace("'", "''"]);
```

This time I got no error, but also no results despite several matching titles in the table. In fact, running this query actually even shows multiple results:

```sql
SELECT name FROM folders WHERE name ILIKE '%let''s do it%'
```

**Second experiment**

Same thing with an injection-friendly code that succeeds beautifully:

```js
const res = pg.query(`SELECT name FROM folders WHERE name ILIKE '%${searchString.replace("'", "''")}%'`);
```

**Result**

I'm still not getting any success with the parameterized queries... Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tried everything with the latest pg package 8.8.0, node 12/14/16/18, postgres Postgres 13 and it all works for me: your initial code (and my answer lol). We will need more data on your environment to reproduce it (node version, pg version, etc)

Comment: I'll try to investigate on the Postgres version. The issue is occuring on postgres12.8 (AWS RDS version)

Comment: I'd suggest installing fresh postgres locally and trying it with your code. If that works, then the issue is on the RDS side. If it doesn't, then it's something with your code (which works for me) environment, and maybe try moving it elsewhere to debug further

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the problem is not with the quote symbol, but with the percent symbols. Your initial code should work, just move percent symbols out of the param:

```
const searchString = "%let's do it%";
const res = pg.query(`SELECT name FROM folders WHERE name ILIKE CONCAT('%', $1, '%')`, [searchString]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that did't seems to do the job for me. Postgres throwing a new error `42P18: could not determine data type of parameter $1`, forcing me to specify `CONCAT('%', $1::text, '%')`, but still, back to the same error again :(